# Heroku mongodb data migration methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, data-conversion

We have a Heroku NodeJS application and have been unable to run our data migrations successfully. We're using MongoDB and continuously encountering problems with legacy data sets from old data models not being converted properly.

I'm tempted to start building and managing a library of scripts, but don't think this is an ideal solution.

In a short past life with Ruby, I remember the rake commands being incredibly easy. Ideally, I'd love to use something like that. Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I see two votes to close the question and would certainly appreciate comments as to why that's being suggested. Maybe we can improve the question or I'd be happy to remove if it's inappropriate.